Inconsistent behavior of float datatype in Pandas dataframe for high precision decimal values
Pandas dataframe gives incorrect decimal values with high precisions.
For example:
The data in oracle tables are
45.200000000000003
12.699999999999999
99.745663
The data type in oracle is number(28,15)
When I do
dataframe=pandas.read_sql_query('select * from schema.table',connection)
print(df['columnname'])

the result set is
0  45.2
1  12.7
3  99.745663
Then I tried to format the float data by
pandas.set_option('display.precision', 15)

The result has become
0  45.200000000000003
1  12.699999999999999
3  99.745662999999993
For some reason the last record was modified.
